# Share messages between Android Devices

Tags: android, android-networking

I have 4 Android Devices in vicinity, running my custom app. I want the app to be able to send messages to one another, either one-to-one or as a broadcast.

How can i do this?
It would be perfect if the devices can discover each other as well (or i can pre-configure that in some way).

There is no internet connection or a central server in this solution.

Comment: NFS? I think you meant NFC. In any case Jasper, what is your minimum api level? How much data do you want to send between them? Describe the use case if you can. There are several ways to do it. Your exact use case will determine which way is better. You could use Wifi Direct, Bluetooth DNLA for the negotiation, NFC, QR codes on the screen, infrasound, a combination of these technologies, or something else entirely.

Comment: Try bluetooh data sending you can do bluetooth chat. there are codes on google to do so check this https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat

Comment: Stephan> API Level not a issue. Data exchanged will be very short infrequent message texts, distance between devices can be within 100 feet or so. The app must send/receive the msg. Based on msg recvd the app may reply with a msg or do nothing or do something. I m fine with broadcast solution, so if msg is not meant for a device, it can ignore it.

Comment: Abhinav> I guess Bluetooth has a v short range only a few feet.

Comment: Bluetooth has a range of 10 meters (or 32 feet). If two devices are not near each other, perhaps they could go through the two other devices as go-betweens, therefore extending their range. In any case, "Wifi direct" is probably what you want, since all your phones seem to be new enough. Wifi direct creates its very own wifi network, and therefore can work in the middle of nowhere. I'd suggest you research that topic.

Comment: Stephen> WiFi direct looks good, except that it is a P2P, and i need a broadcast, and apparently it works well in line-of-sight, not otherwise. If this doesn't work well i will fall back on (low-end/not-costly) Router based solution (but no internet) - any pointers to that?

Answer (score 0):

The new [Nearby Messages](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/overview) sounds perfect for what you want to do

Comment: Tim> I guess this API requires your devices to be already on some sort of network like Wifi or Ethernet?

Comment: Nearby API documentation though states as a pre-requisite that you must: "Connect multiple Android devices to the same network with multicast enabled."

Comment: Youre completely right, I have nfi where I got that audio thing from

Comment: Digging up an old convo, [Nearby Messages](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/) appears to be what I was thinking of, not Nearby Connections which is what I originally linked

Answer (score 0):

Look also at [AllJoyn Framework](https://allseenalliance.org/developers/learn/core)
There are more information [here](https://allseenalliance.org/developers/learn/core/standard-core).

Comment: llya> So this too requires your devices to be on a WiFi network?